# How to use p3dfft multiple times for different dimensions? Any idea?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, fft

I want to use p3dfft first NxNxN and in-between 2Nx2Nx2N dimensions. I have tried to implement that, it shows

```
 P3DFFT Setup error: the problem is already initialized. 
 Currently multiple setups not supported.
 Quit the library using p3dfft_clean before initializing another setup
```

or if I tried to set up p3dfft 2 times (without cleaning first one) it shows error code 139. See below,

```
===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 4127 RUNNING AT localhost.localdomain
=   EXIT CODE: 139
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

I was trying to making header file and made one function for given dimension but still error is there when function called 2 times for 2 different dimensions.

Comment: `Quit the library using p3dfft_clean before initializing another setup` looks like it says about what you need to do.  Did, after running it the first time, you use `p3dfft_clean` to clean up after the first run?

Comment: I tried both ways just for error and trial. When I clean up using p3dfft_clean and set up new p3dfft for different dimensions, first error comes "Multiple set ups not supported" , while  without cleaning it shows error code 139.